# Complex integration with fractional powers

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How would one compute
$$
\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^{n + \frac{1}{2}}}{(z^{\frac{1}{2}} + 1)^2}\ dz,
$$
for an integer $n$ and where $\gamma$ denotes the closed unit circle contour, that is using complex analysis. Can residue theory be applied to this?

#### History

I am interested in computing
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{inx}}{1+\cos(x/2)}\ dx, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
using complex methods. Setting $z = e^{ix}$, we then obtain that $z^{1/2} + z^{-1/2} = 2\cos(x/2)$, which after factoring yields
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{inx}}{1+\cos(x/2)}\ dx = \int_{\gamma}\frac{z^{n + \frac{1}{2}}}{(z^{\frac{1}{2}} + 1)^2}\ dz,
$$
where $\gamma : [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\gamma(t) = e^{it}.$

Comment: What's the domain of the integerand?

Comment: As a first step, you could tell us what is the meaning of $z^{1/2}$.

Comment: Hi vitamind and Jose, thank you for your comments. I have expanded on my question. I hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $z=w^2$ so that your integral becomes

$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{w^{2n + 1}2w}{(w + 1)^2}\ dw,$$

where $\Gamma$ is one-half of the unit circle.

The choice of $\Gamma$ depends where you choose your square roots.

(If $\Gamma$ goes from $0$ to $\pi,$ then you can return along the X-axis.)